# warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout. and no branches found

Tags: git, libvpx

I'm trying to checkout libvpx but I get the error below.

```
sudo git clone http://git.chromium.org/webm/libvpx.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /opt/ffmpeg/sources/libvpx/.git/
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
cd libvpx/
git branch -a
<nothing>
```

I've even tried to checkout the master branch specifically but still nothing.

```
sudo git clone http://git.chromium.org/webm/libvpx.git -b master
Initialized empty Git repository in /opt/ffmpeg/sources/libvpx/.git/
warning: Remote branch master not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the remote git repositories not create the `master` branch. You can use `git branch -r` to look the other branch, and use `git checkout -b xxx origin/xxx` to checkout a remote branch code. Or try `git help symbolic-ref` for more information.